# Comments and Link Sharing Not Working

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-comments

The Facebook comments box, along with sharing links via input box on our fan page is not working with new content on my site - see example: thelincolnite.co.uk/2011/10/police-search-for-homeless-missing-girl-18/.

This issue began yesterday (Monday, October 3rd, 2011) and is *only present on NEW content*. The comment box is now disabled on new content and when sharing a link on our Facebook fan page non of the meta data is pulled.

The Facebook linter shows various errors — [see here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://thelincolnite.co.uk/2011/10/police-search-for-homeless-missing-girl-18/). However these problems are false, as the data its saying isn't present is infact present.

This is restricting us from sharing our content with our page and stopping commenters from engaging on our site.

Any advice on the issue would be appreciated. It's worth noting that all content prior to yesterday renders fine, [as can be seen here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://thelincolnite.co.uk/2011/10/no-weekly-black-bin-collections-for-lincoln/).

Thanks.

Comment: I have been getting this exact same problem on my site.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that the link displays all properties ok when checked with OpenGraph.in — http://www.opengraph.in/?url=http://thelincolnite.co.uk/2011/10/police-search-for-homeless-missing-girl-18/.

Comment: What I found interesting is that some of Facebook's own pages are throwing up errors: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fbugs%2F151722701585098

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem with my site. http://opengraph.in was displaying the correct Title/Image but http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/ was showing the wrong data (ie, not the Title/Image I had specified on the page I was trying to share)

The url I was trying to share was of the form:

http://mysite.com?page=page_id

Turns out, Facebook ignores GET variables when generating the canonical URL for the share. So, facebook thought every share for my site was a share for my homepage (not a specific subpage)

I fixed this my making the subpage part of the actual url:

http://mysite.com/page/page_id

And now all of my shares have the correct Image/Title.